# Como Compartilhar Imagem e texto

Tags: android

No meu aplicativo eu tenho um botão compartilhar, ate então ele só compartilha uma imagem eu tava querendo que ele compartilhasse um texto também , uma referência do meu aplicativo o nome

Código que eu uso para compartilhar imagem

```
int drawableId = getResources().getIdentifier(listenerItem.nome_foto, "drawable", getPackageName());
            Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(drawableId);
            Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap(drawable);
            Uri imageUri = getImageUri(this, bitmap);

            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
            sendIntent.setType("image/jpg");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.compartilhar)));
```

Comment: Gostaria de saber se esse código de compartilhar Imagem funciona atualmente, estou enfrentando problemas para compartilhar a imagem

Comment: Funciona sim...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimente alterar o *MIME* para:

```
sendIntent.setType("*/*");
```

E acrescentar o texto assim:

```
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Lorem ipsum dolor...");
```